# Error while parsing JSON from Database for Android App. (No tag defined)

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have created a json for getting mysql data for a news app in android & ios. Whenever I am parsing the json.php file it returns "No tag defined" and the app stopped working both android and ios. Here is the code sample that I was trying to work out.

```
    <?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","####","###");

if (!$con){

            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("###", $con);

$date = date('Y-m-d');
//$date = '2014-02-01';
$year = substr($date, 0, -6);
$month = substr($date, 5, -3);
$day = substr($date,-2, 10);

     if($month==01) $month1="january";
else if($month==02) $month1="february";
else if($month==03) $month1="march";
else if($month==04) $month1="april";
else if($month==05) $month1="may";
else if($month==06) $month1="june";
else if($month==07) $month1="july";
else if($month==08) $month1="august";
else if($month==09) $month1="september";
else if($month==10) $month1="october";
else if($month==11) $month1="november";
else if($month==12) $month1="december";

$table=$month1.$year;
//$table = $february2014;


if(isset($_REQUEST['tag']) && $_REQUEST['tag'] != ''){

    $tag = $_REQUEST['tag'];

    if($tag =='category_page' && isset($_REQUEST['menu_id']) && $_REQUEST['menu_id'] !='' ) {

         $menu_id = $_REQUEST['menu_id'];

                try{

                        $i=0;
                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE menu_id=1 AND news_date ='$date'");

                        if($query === FALSE) {
                            die(mysql_error());
                        }

                        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

                        $responce[$i]['news_id'] = $data['news_id'];
                        $responce[$i]['news_title'] = str_replace("\t",'',str_replace("\r\n\t",'', substr(strip_tags($data['news_title']),0,110)));
                            $responce[$i]['news_reporter'] = str_replace("\t",'',str_replace("\r\n\t",'', substr(strip_tags($data['news_reporter']),0,110)));
                            $responce[$i]['news_details'] = str_replace("\t",'',str_replace("\r\n\t",'', substr(strip_tags($data['news_details']),0,110)));
                            $responce[$i]['photo'] = $data['photo'];
                            $responce[$i]['path'] = 'admin/'.str_replace('\\','',$data['path']);
                            $responce[$i]['menu_id'] = $data['menu_id'];
                            $responce[$i]['menu_type'] = $data['menu_type'];
                            $responce[$i]['news_publish_status'] = $data['news_publish_status'];
                            $responce[$i]['news_order'] = $data['news_order'];
                            $responce[$i]['news_date'] = $data['news_date'];
                            $responce[$i]['news_time'] = $data['news_time'];
                            $responce[$i]['added_by'] = $data['added_by'];
                            $responce[$i]['directory'] = $data['directory'];
                            $responce[$i]['read_number'] = $data['read_number'];
                            $responce[$i]['comment_number'] = $data['comment_number'];
                            $responce[$i]['news_comment_table_name'] = $data['news_comment_table_name'];    

                            $i++;
                        }

                    } catch(Exception $e) {

                        $responce = 'Exception: '.$e->getMessage();

                    }

     }else{

         $responce = "category or Menu id is not Defined";
     }

    echo json_encode($responce);
}else{

   echo json_encode("No tag Defined");

}
?>
```

not getting any way to fix it up. can any one help me out.Would appreciate your kind assistance.

Comment: $tag = $_REQUEST['tag']; how are you getting this $tag ? Is it just empty string?

Comment: yes just a empty string.

Comment: Well, In your code if $tag is empty, it goes to else part which is  echo json_encode("No tag Defined");

Comment: $tag should not be empty.

Comment: Basically it supposed to fetch the menu id. @Sagar in this case what can be the alternative

Comment: if do not want to test $tag emptiness then remove that if else statement.

Comment: Can you please mark which portion you are talking about to remove

Comment: if(isset($_REQUEST['tag']) && $_REQUEST['tag'] != ''){
}else{

   echo json_encode("No tag Defined");

}

Comment: If menu id did not get set with value then echo json_encode($responce); would not execute;

Comment: Or try this if statement 
if(isset($_REQUEST['tag'])){
Instead of 
if(isset($_REQUEST['tag']) && $_REQUEST['tag'] != ''){

Comment: After turning off the above mentioned code blocks it is returning "category or Menu id is not Defined"

Comment: Now the output is blank nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['tag'])){
```

Instead of

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['tag']) && $_REQUEST['tag'] != ''){
```

Comment: did so but the output is empty and not working around

Comment: Try sql query in phpmyadmin and see you get data back or not?
"SELECT * FROM $table WHERE menu_id=1 AND news_date ='$date'"

Comment: SELECT *
FROM may2015
WHERE menu_id =1
AND news_date = '2015-05-23' returns data

Comment: Print value of  $responce without json_encode and see it prints or not?

Comment: No output even i am thinking whether this block is necessary or not with tag above mysql query

Comment: then remove 
 if($tag =='category_page' && isset($_REQUEST['menu_id']) && $_REQUEST['menu_id'] !='' ) {
and its else part

Comment: After removing these tag code block the output comes with at http://dainikazadi.net/JSON/new/json.php

Comment: The output is coming, its time to check with android app & ios app by applying the above json URL whether it comes out or not

Comment: OK. Best of luck with that :)

Comment: Can i get your email to communicate further if you dont mind to help